# Mapping processing control to REST

Tags: rest

Let's say you have a service that manages long-running (automatic) processes. Process  can be started, paused, resumed or cancelled. As an example, consider video conversion or 3d printing. A list of all previously run and currently running processes is always available.

I am trying to map this concept to REST and having some problems.

Start can potentially be mapped to `POST /processes`, but it feels weird. Start is not create, and having `POST` mean create item for some collections, and start process for others sounds confusing. But that part is less important.

Pause, resume and cancel is where I stumble. I could potentially see it as `PATCH` — but what is the difference between RESTful and RPC approaches then?

> With PATCH, however, the enclosed entity contains a set of
>   instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the
>   origin server should be modified to produce a new version.

If the instruction specifies that status should be set to paused, this seems to break encapsulation and feels arbitrary — pause can potentially affect much more than just status (any inner tasks etc).

If the instruction is literally `pause` — this is better, but what's the benefit over RPC if all clients have to know these specific messages anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` to a collection resource `/processes` creates a new process in a default state. The response contains a header

```
Location: /processes/42
```

The state of this process can be retrieved by

```
GET /processes/42
```

which could be

```
{
  "id": 42,
  "state": "created"
}
```

If the client wants to change the state of this process, he could

```
POST /process/42

{
  "state": "started"
}
```

Note that the JSON is incomplete. This pattern is often used in a `POST` request to an existing resource and can be interpreted as 'update the resource with the provided parameters'. Of course the server is free to ignore this request because server state would be corrupted or because of other reasons.

REST is about resources and their representation. The REST client has *client* state which may not match the server state. And not every transition in server state requested by the client may be doable.

Comment: Why is it better to provide state change as the new value instead of command (like doing a `POST` with body consisting of `pause`)? Seems like both have the same discoverability problems — you have to know the exact name of target state or you have to know the exact name of command?

Comment: "Why is it better to provide state change as the new value instead of command?" - Because that's the difference between REST and RPC. "Seems like both have the same discoverability problems" - Yes, but that's a different question.

Comment: OK, I see (actually I am probably incorrect about discoverability either way as media types should be known). I still have some questions but I'll accept this one and ask them separately.